# TensorFlow (any version > 2.5.0) on M1 Mac: No code completion in PyCharm

Tags: python, tensorflow, autocomplete, pycharm, code-completion

I am using JetBrain's PyCharm IDE to work with TensorFlow on a M1 Mac machine.
I have installed TensorFlow using the following commands in the given order:

```
conda create -n data-science -y python=3.9
conda activate data-science
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps
pip install tensorflow-macos
pip install tensorflow-metal
```

For installing Conda, I followed Apple's official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/)

I can import TensorFlow without problems; the version number it prints is `2.8.0`.
However, I am not getting any code completion suggestions.
When typing `tensorflow.keras.l`, it should suggest `layers`, or `losses`.
As the attached screenshot shows, I am not getting anything usable:
[image]

I have restarted the IDE, invalidated any caches, re-indexed the project, and re-created the environment from scratch multiple times, all to no avail. Other suggestions are working as expected (such as the `os.path.join` line in the screenshot). What puzzles me is that, in another project on the very same machine (M1 Mac), I am using TensorFlow `2.5.0`, which gives me the desired code suggestions.

The inability to get code suggestion for more recent TensorFlow versions has stopped me from updating to, e.g., version `2.8.0`. What are your suggestions to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you please try as discussed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/53144#issuecomment-1030773659)? Thanks!

Comment: @TFer2, this has solved my issue until an official fix becomes available! Thanks for pointing me to it; if you like, you can write an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For code completion you can follow below workaround

```
from tensorflow import keras

if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    from keras.api._v2 import keras
```

For more details please refer [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/53144#issuecomment-1030773659).